# What is wrong with the way I am handling these variables in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Originally I wanted to use node.js, but after an entire day of frustration, I switched to using jquery and mySQL. The logins seem to be working, but something is wrong in the way it is handling variables. All I want to do is update the database with two things: score and name. Here is the code I modded for my project in PHP:

```
<?php


$db = "myDatabaseNameIsCorrect";//Your database name
$dbu = "soIsMyUsername";//Your database username
$dbp = "AndMyPassword";//Your database users' password
$host = "localhost";//MySQL server - usually localhost

$dblink = mysql_connect($host,$dbu,$dbp);
$seldb = mysql_select_db($db);

if(isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['this.score'])){

     //Lightly sanitize the GET's to prevent SQL injections and possible XSS attacks
     $name = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']));
     $score = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['this.score']));
     $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$db`.`scores` (`id`,`name`,`score`) VALUES ('','$name','$score');");

     if($sql){

          //The query returned true - now do whatever you like here.
          echo 'Your score was saved. Congrats!';

     }else{

          //The query returned false - you might want to put some sort of error reporting here. Even logging the error to a text file is fine.
          echo 'There was a problem saving your score. Please try again later.';

     }

}else{
     echo 'Your name or score wasnt passed in the request. Make sure you add ?name=NAME_HERE&score=1337 to the tags.';
}

mysql_close($dblink);//Close off the MySQL connection to save resources.
?>
```

And here is the JS! that runs the PHP:

```
let gameoverScene = new Phaser.Scene('GameOver');



gameoverScene.create = function(){
          this.laughSound=this.sound.add('laughSound')
            this.gameW = this.sys.game.config.width;
            this.gameH = this.sys.game.config.height;

    this.goToTitle=function(){

       var name = prompt('Enter your name');
        jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'savescores.php?name=' +name +'&score=' + this.score,
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {functionname: 'add', arguments: [name, this.score]},

    success: function (obj, textstatus) {
                  if( !('error' in obj) ) {
                      yourVariable = obj.result;
                  }
                  else {
                      console.log(obj.error);
                  }
            }
});

        this.scene.start('Title')
    };
```

I also tried changing the data type and that didn't work, but I'm not ruling it out yet as a problem.

Here are links to the project and the database:

www.igglepud.com/DeerDefender/Testing

www.igglepud.com/DeerDefender/Testing/getscores.php

This is the error I get:

```
gameover.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'error' in 
Your name or score wasnt passed in the request. Make sure you add ?name=NAME_HERE&score=1337 to the tags.
    at Object.success (gameover.js:20)
    at fire (jquery.js:3268)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3398)
    at done (jquery.js:9305)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:9548)
```

Comment: You might want to consider binding your data to a prepared query. Don't think that's the problem though.

Comment: What does that mean? I've only been using PHP for about two hours now.

Comment: Also, what errors are you getting, and are you actually executing the query? I'm missing where the query gets executed.

Comment: `isset($_GET['this.score'])` will silently fail. Protip: don't use `isset()` until things are working.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Looks like you are mixing GET and POST types, your ajax call is setting type to POST but then encoding the GET params in the URL. Can you get the vars on the PHP side using $_POST?

Comment: You could try $_POST or $_REQUEST, that would fix the problem @radcore mentioned.

Comment: Oh, I forgot the errors. Thanks! I'll post those.

Comment: i am not sure if you need semicolon here

gameoverScene.create = function(){
          this.laughSound=this.sound.add('laughSound') <<<<<<
            this.gameW = this.sys.game.config.width;
            this.gameH = this.sys.game.config.height;

Comment: Couldn't hurt. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the error you're getting is because, in the JavaScript, obj (or the parameter in obj's position) [is a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403441/jquery-ajax-pass-success-data-into-separate-function), not an array.

You can see some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209671/jquery-how-to-find-out-what-the-ajax-error-is) of how you can properly check for and catch errors.

Edit:
So, in regards to your question about the score variable.

It's important to note that there are 2 **types** of variables at play here.

The first one is PHP GET variables. PHP GET variables are set via the following format:

```
var=value
```

You can set these variables by calling a PHP script like this:

```
script.php?var1=value1&var2=value2&var3=value3 // etc...
```

You can access them like this:

```
echo $_GET["var1"];
echo $_GET["var2"];
echo $_GET["var3"];
```

Which produces the result:

```
value1
value2
value3
```

The second variable at play is a JavaScript variable. Those can only be accessed in JavaScript. a JavaScript variable means nothing in PHP.

So, let's examine what you're doing from the JavaScript:

```
url: 'savescores.php?name=' +name +'&score=' + this.score,
```

For the purpose of explaining let's say name = Chipster, and this.score = 123.

What this code will do is try to open the following file:

```
savescores.php?name=Chipster&score=123
```

Remembering that PHP GET variables are set by the format `script.php?var1=value1&var2=value2&var3=value3 // etc...` we can see that there are 2 GET variables available from the PHP script called name and score. Thus, to access score from PHP you need to do it like this:

```
echo $_GET["score"];
```

This will output `123` in our example.

Comment: So if I understand this right, it is throwing an error because it is searching through the properties of "obj" looking for something, but those properties do not exist because strings don't have them.

Comment: I'm guessing that "functionname" and "yourVariable" probably need to be changed as well?

Comment: That's one way of putting it, yes.

Comment: Not sure about function name, just you will need to change myVariable. Really, all myVariable needs to be is "myVariable=obj;"

Comment: I read more about the success function, and it has a third parameter. I moved obj there(because the third paramater is related to the PHP request, could still be totally wrong though) and the errors went away, but it still won't update the database. (edit) That's odd, I should still get something in the console, so that must be a wrong move as the PHP request seems to not happen at all.

Comment: OK, found a wonderful little checkbox in Chrome to log XMLHttpRequests. Name gets passed fine, but score is undefined.

Comment: @Igglepud That could be because you're searching for "this.score" Try just "score" instead.

Comment: But in the game, this.score is the score I want to record. How do I tell the php to post this.score to the score field in the database? That's where my disconnect is. I don't understand how to grab a specific variable and post it. I'm fine scrapping all this and writing from scratch, I just don't know how. And as mentioned above, if an easier way exists without Jquery, I'm all ears.

Comment: @Igglepud I updated my answer to explain PHP GET variables a bit. Hope it helps :D

Comment: Thanks! I still can't get it to work, but at least now I know what the PHP is actually doing. Reading some more, I also see that AJAX is the magic bridge between Javascript and PHP. Does that sound right to you?

Comment: OMG!!!! *FIREWORKS* *CHEERS OF MILLIONS OF PEOPLE* I went back into the php file and changed post to GET...and it saved my scores to the database! It still gives me the error about using "in", but honestly at this point I'm happy. I have a functioning high score table.

Comment: OK, a little early for all that. Score always posts as 0, but still....this is a HUGE step in the right direction. Thanks so much for all the help!

Comment: Fixed...just more bad programming on my part.

Comment: Hey, you're new to PHP. It's a learning process. Glad I could help, and thanks for accepted answer status! :D

Comment: Yes. AJAX is is the bridge between PHP and JS, in your example anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This may not solve your problem, but one issue I see with your code is calling strip_tags (or another function that alters the string) after it has already been quoted for insertion with mysql_real_escape_string may defeat the purpose of mysql_real_escape_string. It should be the very last function called on data before it's inserted.

Also, if score is an integer string, intval serves just as well as mysql_real_escape_string for sanitizing integers for insertion.

EDIT: You're also checking for GET variables in the PHP when the submission method used in the jQuery is POST. Try looking at $_POST instead of $_GET on the PHP side. You don't need to put variables in a query string if you're putting them in the request body via POST either.

Comment: OK, I thought the GET was pulling a variable from my JS! to post to the database. Thank you!

Comment: I changed all the GET to POST and I get the same error.

Comment: I have to tell you the AJAX request would be a heck of a lot more straightforward using ordinary XMLHttpRequest than that jQuery code, IMHO. Are you sure the POST field isn't called "score" rather than "this.score"? The later sounds like the "score" property of some JavaScript object or another that I'm not able to identify from reading the code.

Comment: this.score is the Javascript object for the player's score. I put that there because I thought it was pulling that variable to post to the database. I'll try losing the "this."***** tried it, same error.

Comment: The error message seems to be telling you that you're trying to use the JavaScript "in" operator to find a property in a string. The "in" operator is used to determine whether an object has the specified property. Are you passing the arguments to the success handler in the correct order?

Comment: OK, the ones in gameover.js  need to read as "this.score" or it throws undefined errors. The ones in the PHP file don't seemto matter, I get the same error either way, which leads me to think the problem is somewhere else. Maybe the isset like Mario mentioned above?

Comment: " Are you passing the arguments to the success handler in the correct order?" I have no idea. Is the success handler the part with three different outcomes?(edit) Nevermind, I see now. I was looking at the PHP file. It's looking for it in "obj", and I don't see "obj" declared anywhere.

Comment: No, it's the JavaScript function where you're looking for "error" in a string rather than an object.