# renderAjax failed to return data

Tags: yii2, render, ajaxform

I did this in the past year and it works just fine. Until recently I encounter this problem which I don't know what caused it.

Here I'm trying to pass **supplierID** from a **(1)form** through **(2)ajax javascript** and return the **(3)data from AdminController** to a **(4)div** in the same view

**(1)form**:-

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
 'id'=>'chatform'
]);?>
<div class="box-body">
 <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>No</th>
   <th>Supplier</th>
   <th>Option(s)</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  <?php 
  for($x = 0; $x < count($supplierChatInfoListTable); $x++){ ?>  

  <tr>
   <td>
    <?=$x+1?>
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="hidden" name="supplierID" id="supplierID" class="form-control" 
      value="<?=$supplierChatInfoListTable[$x]['supplierID']?>" style="width: 50px">
    </div>
   </td>
   <td >
    <h4><?=$supplierChatInfoListTable[$x]['supplierFirstname']?></h4>
   </td>
   <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnchat"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
   </td>
  </tr>

  <?php } ?>

  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  <tr>
   <th>No</th>
   <th>Supplier</th>
   <th>Option(s)</th>
  </tr>
  </tfoot>
 </table>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end();?>
```

and here is my **(2)javascript** running in the same view:-

```
<?php
$urproudcode= Url::to(['admin/chatinfo2pass']);

$this->registerJs("
 $(function(){
  $('.btnchat').click(function(){
    var supplierID = $('#supplierID').val();
    $.ajax({
      'url':'".$urproudcode."',
      'data':{supplierID:supplierID},
      'method':'POST',
      beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        $.blockUI({
          message: 'Processing...',
          css: {
            border: 'none',
            padding: '15px',
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
            opacity: .5,
            color: '#fff'
          }
        });
      },
      'success':function(data){
        $('.chatmessages').html('Success');
        if(data == 'false'){
          $.unblockUI();
          $('.chatmessages').html('Data False');
        }else{
          $.unblockUI();
          $('.chatmessages').html(data);
        }
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        $.unblockUI();
        $('.chatmessages').html('Failed');
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
   });
  });
 ");
?>
```

**(3)div** with class=chatmessages in the same view

```
<div class="col-md-8 chatmessages">

</div>
```

**(4)actionChatinfo2pass in AdminController**

```
public function actionChatinfo2pass()
{
    $postData = \Yii::$app->request->post('supplierID');

    $supplierID = intval($postData);

    // fetch all supplier for chat
    $supplierChatInfoListTable = SupplierProfile::find()
    ->select(['supplier_profileID AS supplierID','supplier_profile.first_name AS supplierFirstname', 
    'supplier_profile.middle_name AS supplierMiddlename', 'supplier_profile.last_name AS 
    supplierLastname', 'login_profile.login_profileID AS loginID', 'status_login.status_loginID AS 
    statusLoginID', 'status_login.description AS statusLogindesc'])
    ->leftJoin('login_profile', 'login_profile.login_profileID = supplier_profile.login_profile_ID')
    ->leftJoin('status_login', 'status_login.status_loginID = login_profile.status_login_ID')
    //->where(['=', 'status_login.description', $activeSupplier])
    ->orderBy(['supplier_profile.supplier_profileID' => SORT_ASC])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();

    $dataSend['supplierChatInfoListTable'] = $supplierChatInfoListTable;

    $this->layout = 'admin/main';
    $html= $this->renderAjax('@app/views/admin/displaychatmessage.php',$dataSend);
    echo $html;
}
```

But it return the 'same' supplierID for both supplier as show below:

[image: Updated div result from displaychatmessage.php on ajax call]

and browser console give me this error?**(updated)**:-

[image: Updated Ajax Error Message when Page Load and error after click]

btw, this is the content of **displaychatmessage.php** (I just try to display supllierID and their name)

```
    <!-- DIRECT CHAT WARNING -->
      <div class="box box-warning direct-chat direct-chat-warning">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
          <h3 class="box-title">Direct Chat</h3>

          <div class="box-tools pull-right">
            <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="3 New Messages" class="badge bg-yellow">3</span>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Contacts" data-widget="chat-pane-toggle">
              <i class="fa fa-comments"></i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body">
          <!-- Conversations are loaded here -->
          <div class="direct-chat-messages">
            <!-- Message. Default to the left -->
            <div class="direct-chat-msg">
              <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                <?php for($z = 0; $z < count($supplierChatInfoListTable); $z++){?>
                <span class="direct-chat-name pull-left">Supplier ID: <?=$supplierChatInfoListTable[$z]['supplierID']?>, <?=$supplierChatInfoListTable[$z]['supplierFirstname']?> <?=$supplierChatInfoListTable[$z]['supplierMiddlename']?> <?=$supplierChatInfoListTable[$z]['supplierLastname']?></span>
                <?php }?>
                <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">23 Jan 2:00 pm</span>
              </div>
              <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->
              <img class="direct-chat-img" src="dist/img/user1-128x128.jpg" alt="Message User Image"><!-- /.direct-chat-img -->
              <div class="direct-chat-text">
                Is this template really for free? That's unbelievable!
              </div>
              <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.direct-chat-msg -->

            <!-- Message to the right -->
            <div class="direct-chat-msg right">
              <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                <span class="direct-chat-name pull-right">Sarah Bullock</span>
                <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-left">23 Jan 2:05 pm</span>
              </div>
              <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->
              <img class="direct-chat-img" src="dist/img/user3-128x128.jpg" alt="Message User Image"><!-- /.direct-chat-img -->
              <div class="direct-chat-text">
                You better believe it!
              </div>
              <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.direct-chat-msg -->
          </div>
          <!--/.direct-chat-messages-->

          <!-- Contacts are loaded here -->
          <div class="direct-chat-contacts">
            <ul class="contacts-list">
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <img class="contacts-list-img" src="dist/img/user1-128x128.jpg" alt="User Image">

                  <div class="contacts-list-info">
                        <span class="contacts-list-name">
                          Count Dracula
                          <small class="contacts-list-date pull-right">2/28/2015</small>
                        </span>
                    <span class="contacts-list-msg">How have you been? I was...</span>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.contacts-list-info -->
                </a>
              </li>
              <!-- End Contact Item -->
            </ul>
            <!-- /.contatcts-list -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.direct-chat-pane -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-body -->
        <div class="box-footer">
          <form action="#" method="post">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Type Message ..." class="form-control">
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-flat">Send</button>
                  </span>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-footer-->
      </div>
      <!--/.direct-chat -->
```

Can you help me with this? I don't know where it went wrong.

Comment: As from your code it looks like your Ajax request is throwing some error. You can check the error in browser console or view error message using your code. Check how to view Ajax error in browser console [here.](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-check-ajax-response-in-browser) or Check how to view error message using your code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209671/jquery-how-to-find-out-what-the-ajax-error-is). Add Ajax error message and error code in your question or in a comment here to get further help.

Comment: @MAZ, I already add-in the Ajax error message (in the question section) as you suggest. What should I do from here?

Comment: Do you get this error after clicking the button or before that (on page load)? Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: @MAZ, the updated Ajax error on page load already been pasted in the question section above. You can look at it. It gave me **expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given**. What does it mean by this?

Comment: Hey @MAZ. I already got it to return the data! Instead of using `var dataform = $('#chatform').serializeArray();` I used `var supplierID = $('#supplierID').val();`. And change the `'data':dataform,` to `'data':{supplierID:supplierID},`. But it returns the same supplierID even though I click on the second supplier on the list. See the image **Updated Ajax Error Message** above it gave me **Found 2 elements with non-unique id #supplierID**. I reckon it has to do with this.

Comment: From the updated error image it looks like you are getting error on server side because of your "@app/views/admin/displaychatmessage.php" file. Can you post content of this file? Also update your js code changes in question.

Comment: The JS code already been updated. As well as the div called displaymessage.php image result. I also posted the content of displaychatmessage.php as requested. Hopefully you can see what went wrong @MAZ.

Comment: As you have mentioned you are getting same supplierID on clicking both supplier. This problem is caused because in your js code you are getting supplierID by id of the input i.e '#supplierID', and according to your html code the input elements of both of the suppliers have same value in their id attribute i.e 'supplierID'. So you need to make some changes in your code. As I cannot add much description in the comment so i'm adding an answer with updated code, so that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned you are getting same `supplierID` on clicking both supplier. This problem is caused because in your js code you are getting `supplierID` by id of the input i.e `'#supplierID'`, and according to your html code the input elements of both of the suppliers have same value in their id attribute i.e 'supplierID', because of that every time js will get value from first input element with id attribute value 'supplierID'. So you need to make some changes in your html and js code. As there is separate edit button for each supplier so instead of using input to store `supplierID` value you can store it in a data attribute in the edit button. So your updated html code would become

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
 'id'=>'chatform'
]);?>
<div class="box-body">
 <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>No</th>
   <th>Supplier</th>
   <th>Option(s)</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  <?php 
  for($x = 0; $x < count($supplierChatInfoListTable); $x++){ 
    $supID = $supplierChatInfoListTable[$x]['supplierID']; ?>  

  <tr>
   <td>
    <?=$x+1?>
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="hidden" name="<?='supplierID'.$supID?>" id="<?='supplierID'.$supID?>" class="form-control" 
      value="<?=$supID?>" style="width: 50px">
    </div>
   </td>
   <td >
    <h4><?=$supplierChatInfoListTable[$x]['supplierFirstname']?></h4>
   </td>
   <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnchat" data-supplierID="<?=$supID?>"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
   </td>
  </tr>

  <?php } ?>

  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  <tr>
   <th>No</th>
   <th>Supplier</th>
   <th>Option(s)</th>
  </tr>
  </tfoot>
 </table>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end();?>
```

And then get the `supplierID` of clicked supplier from data attribute of button in js. So your js code would become

```
<?php
$urproudcode= Url::to(['admin/chatinfo2pass']);

$this->registerJs("
 $(function(){
  $('.btnchat').click(function(){
    var supplierID = $(this).attr('data-supplierID');
    $.ajax({
      'url':'".$urproudcode."',
      'data':{supplierID:supplierID},
      'method':'POST',
      beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        $.blockUI({
          message: 'Processing...',
          css: {
            border: 'none',
            padding: '15px',
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
            opacity: .5,
            color: '#fff'
          }
        });
      },
      'success':function(data){
        $('.chatmessages').html('Success');
        if(data == 'false'){
          $.unblockUI();
          $('.chatmessages').html('Data False');
        }else{
          $.unblockUI();
          $('.chatmessages').html(data);
        }
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        $.unblockUI();
        $('.chatmessages').html('Failed');
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
   });
  });
 ");
?>
```

I hope your problem will be solved.

Comment: I see. It's working now. So you're saying I can basically ditch the `<input>` element and replace it with `data-supplierID=` as one of the elements in `button`. Are you saying that it doesn't matter how many `<input>` I pass to `ajax` with the same method I used before, I will still get the same error as before? Btw, thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, using the `data-supplierID=` is an easy approach. However you can do that with `<input>` element also, but that would be a little complicated

Comment: Okay. Meaning that there's still a way I can do that using `<input>` element. Will keep that in mind. Thanks for the help btw!

Comment: No problem. Happy to help! :)